# MongoError: The field 'academic_year' must be an accumulator object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregate

I have the following aggregation code which returns all the students for each school in my school ID list. For each student there is an academic year ID that looks like this: ObjectId("5ede4682341e8426f1cf6285")

```
return await this.studentSchoolModel.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          school: { $in: schoolIDs },
        },
      },

      {
        $group: {
          _id: '$school',
          academic_years: '$academic_year',
          total_students: { $sum: 1 },
        },
      },
    ]);
```

If I try to group by the school, it works, but if I try to group by the school and academic year I get the following error:

```
MongoError: The field 'academic_year' must be an accumulator object
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I want the output for each school to look like this:

```
_id: 12345678 //schoolID
academic_years: {
          _id: 1111111 //academic year ID
          total_students: 5 //number of students in that year
          },
          {
          _id: 2222222 //academic year ID
          total_students: 8 //number of students in that year
          }
```

Comment: `academic_years` is the field you try to create using `$group`. You you need to specify how you need to group it, Eg:  `academic_years: {$first: '$academic_year'}`. Refer https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/ and if  you ppst your sample data, we will help you

Comment: Thanks @varman. For some reason it won't let me edit my post, but this is my sample data. Each document in the studentSchoolModel looks like this:   {
    _id: 5ee88b5b58113d92dddc3c53,
    school: 5ede3d670ae2e18b856bd389,
    academic_year: 5ede4682341e8426f1cf6285
  }. I want to be able to group by school, with an array for academic years for that school with the total number of pupils for each year. Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$group`

- first group is to group by school and academic year. The second group is to group by school

Here is the code

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": { sc: "$school", ay: "$academic_year" },
      total: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.sc",
      total_students: {
        $push: {
          _id: "$_id.ay",
          total_students: "$total"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pIl4favz2EP)**

Comment: just one more question please, how can I add a lookup to this to get the academic year name for each year, based off the id. Like this: {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'academic_years',
          localField: 'academic_year'.toString(),
          foreignField: '_id'.toString(),
          as: 'academicYearDetails',
        },
      },

Comment: @user15959355 https://mongoplayground.net/p/sD-Di8RQyvT this would help u